# How to restrict a function so that it can't throw any kind of exception 

Tags: java, exception

How to restrict a function so that it can't throw any kind of exception?

Comment: As in: it can't throw any execptions? or as in: it can only throw specific exceptions?

Comment: @assylias it cant throw any exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Catch all exception  in the method.

```
public void myMethod() {
    try {
       // do something
    } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

if you want to catch any kind of Exception or Error including OutOfMemoryError or ThreadDeath etc use

```
    } catch (Throwable t) {
```

Comment: +1 for `e.printStackTrace()` - suppressing exceptions without at least logging them is an incredibly bad idea.

Comment: You might need to wrap that e.printStackTrace() again, this may again throw something.

Comment: @lovewithjava That is an alternative, It wouldn't make sense to catch all exceptions but then declare that it could throw any.  Usually its best to list all the checked exceptions it might throw instead of `throws Exception` unless the list is very long or unknown.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap all of your code in a try catch block.

```
public void someMethod(){
 try{
  //your code
 }catch (Exception e){
   //do nothing
 }
}
```

Read More about exceptions and Try/Catch on the Java Tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html